# Using Phonegap to build application for iOS , Android and Windows Platform

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, cordova

we are new to phonegap, and planning to use phonegap to build the
application for iOS , Android , and Windows platfrom,

have following question ,

1 -- I believe phonegap framework will assist developer to write code
in HTML/Javascript , CSS and it can be written on any machine

2 -- Once we have basic UI , or almost whatever we can do using
phonegap is done, there will be some native handling which should be
specific to native, i.e. using Xcode for iOS , Ecllipse for Andoird
etc...

3 -- Are there any compatibility to run the Phonegap application in
various platform, i heard phonegap app may not run if the Device
browser is not HTML 5 Compatible, Can i use Phonegap app on iPhone3 ,
( first iOS version probably 3)

Comment: Two of the three "questions" are not questions...please try again.  As for the third, yes if the browser doesn't support all the HTML5 features that phonegap implements then it won't run.  However, it should be ok back to iOS 3.1 for most parts.

Comment: WinPhone version of PhoneGap will suck, you can't get around it. Yes, it will work but it'll work horribly and break a lot of things such as *touch gestures* which is just plain unacceptable. Unless you really believe there's value in having a WinPhone version of your app other than "it'd be a nice to have one", don't bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. PhoneGap provides an API (for each platform) and JavaScript library which bridges the gap from your HTML/JavaScript/CSS with the native features of the device. The API and JavaScript Library are actually called `Cordova` (due to the company being bought out and the API and libraries going open source).
2. You will need to use a JavaScript / CSS library for UI - you are building a Web App. You can indeed build native UI if need be and launch the PhoneGap Web App for another part of the app, however this will mean you have to repeat this UI on each platform and without custom code (I think, please correct me if I'm wrong) you cannot go from Web App back to the native UI.
3. This depends on your requirements, if you need it to run on older devices you may hit issues. For all modern/recent devices you should be fine with HTML5 (and a decent UI library such as Sencha Touch and jQuery Mobile).

If you are considering using the `PhoneGap Build` service, you will lose the flexibility for custom code in the different platforms and are restricted to a pure Web App.

Comment: +1 So let says if I were to develop application with BarcodeScanner plugin, in windows OS, can I still build as IOS application via PhoneGap Build service?

Comment: You should probably open up a new question for this, but a quick Google search came up with the following: https://build.phonegap.com/blog/barcodescanner-plugin

Answer (score -3):

1. phonegap is javascript library, which helps you to build an application for any platform  no need to use native things , all phone functionality are available in phoneGap
2. phoneGap is not meant for mobile UI , for that you can use Sencha Touch or Jquery Mobile
3. when you done building an app , phonegap is having build service which will give an installable app for e.g. for android .apk file